How do I work around this Google Identity for iOS error?
I'm using Google Sign-In in a Flutter project with Firebase and AppCheck, but I can't sign in on development builds. I receive a Missing or insufficient permissions error for all Firestore calls. AppCheck debug tokens are entered correctly into Firebase, and other sign-in methods work fine.
Dependencies:
firebase_app_check: 0.3.1+6
google_sign_in: 6.2.2
Problem: google_sign_in installs GoogleSignIn (~> 7.1), but it needs version 8.0 to support AppCheck Debug tokens with the new Google Identity. Until the package updates, I need to turn off Google Identity for iOS in the Cloud Console. However, I encounter a type error when trying to disable it.
Questions:

Where can I report this to Google?
Are there any workarounds?



